# What type of printer to print without leaving the page 'sodden' in ink?

Tags: printer, colors

Many of the (admittedly cheap) printers I've used in the past will literally soak the paper in ink, leaving it damp to the touch for a long period until it dries, and once it does sometimes being wrinkled.

What kind of printers/paper would be needed to apply the ink to the paper smoothly, producing a high-quality full-bleed printout that would be suitable for company headed paper?

Comment: Does the printer have a setting to use less ink? Most of the ones I've seen do that.

Comment: A large-format laser or dye sub printer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most modern Inkjets beyond the very least expensive use a fast drying ink.  Paper is also critical if you are using a higher resolution and output with high coverage on the paper.  Using a high quality photo setting on normal paper will saturate teh page and give poor quality.

Each printer maker usually has a range of paper designed for specific task( photos, graphics,fine art, etc)  [Epson](http://epson.ca/cgi-bin/ceStore/pamHome.jsp?BV_UseBVCookie=yes&iref=estorehome_shopby_paper) has a very wide range.  Having tested a number of different types I can say that the difference in quality and drying time is significant.  Avoid cheap paper and no-name ink and most printers will give very good results.

As noted by @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, a laser or dye sub printer would solve your issue as well.

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for answer. Don't really want to splash out on a laser printer since I'm not doing a great quantity. The paper/ink I've been using isn't great, so I'll invest in something a little better (probably a nicer printer too. I've had EPSON's my whole life, so I'll see what £150-200 will get me nowdays). Thanks.